# Modifying and passing data through nested Handlebars partials

Tags: handlebars.js

How is it possible to modify data from a partial when passing down to its sub-partial (in the context of assemble.io)?
usage is something like this:

```
<!-- index.hbs -->
{{> heroImage src="img.jpg"}}

<!-- heroImage.hbs -->
<div>{{> responsiveImage srcset=src+"480w"}}</div>

<!-- responsiveImage.hbs -->
<img srcset={{srcset}} />
```

I can only pass the `src` data but not using and modifying it, like `src + "something"` or `src"something"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to perform a string concatenation from within a mustache you will need to use a [helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/#helpers) method and invoke it as a [sub expression](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#subexpressions).

Such a helper method could be as simple as the following:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('concat', function () {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0, -1).join('');
});
```

And your heroImage.hbs partial would use this helper in the following way:

```
<div>{{> responsiveImage srcset=(concat src " 480w")}}</div>
```

I have also created an example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/g4ht0mrc/).

Comment: the partial code is missing the 'concat'. compared to the fiddle:  {{> responsiveImage srcset=(concat src " 480w")}}